# CodeMirror 2 - (readonly and editable code)

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Can CodeMirror 2 be used to set part of the code to be uneditable?

I do not wish to do it like [fully editable code](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/TcqAf/).

Example:

Code inline:
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/2cwr3/)

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    //content
}
```

I hope to be able to make Line 1 and 3 uneditable BUT able to edit lines in between them adding characters/spaces increasing the number of lines inside the method as we speak AND still unable to edit the starting and closing bracket lines.

Answer (score 3):

No, but CodeMirror 3.1 and up can do this. See the [`markText`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) method's `readOnly` option.